# Auto refresh value in ListViewItem

Tags: c#, listviewitem, robotics

I'm currently working on an application for an industrial robot. The application connects to all robot controllers in the network and lists them in a ListViewItem. Using a double click on one of the controllers detail information in a second ListVieItem is displayed. Till now I managed to connect to the robot controllers and use the double click to show the information. The problem now is that the value of the variable inside the controller is changing, but I do not know how to adjust my code, so the change will be displayed automatically.

The code I use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using ABB.Robotics.Controllers;
using ABB.Robotics.Controllers.Discovery;
using ABB.Robotics.Controllers.RapidDomain;
using ABB.Robotics.Controllers.IOSystemDomain;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private NetworkScanner networkScanner = null;
        private Controller ctrl = null;
        private Controller controller = null;
        private Task[] tasks = null;
        private NetworkWatcher networkwatcher = null;
        private Num rapidNum;
        private double VarValue = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            networkScanner = new NetworkScanner();
            networkScanner.Scan();
            ControllerInfoCollection controllers = networkScanner.Controllers;
            networkwatcher = new NetworkWatcher(networkScanner.Controllers);

            networkwatcher.Found += new EventHandler<NetworkWatcherEventArgs>(HandleFoundEvent);
            networkwatcher.Lost += new EventHandler<NetworkWatcherEventArgs>(HandleLostEvent);
            networkwatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            foreach (ControllerInfo controller in controllers)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(controller.IPAddress.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(controller.Id);
                item.SubItems.Add(controller.Availability.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(controller.IsVirtual.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(controller.SystemName);
                item.SubItems.Add(controller.Version.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(controller.ControllerName);
                item.Tag = controller;
                this.listControllersView.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.networkwatcher.Lost -= new EventHandler<NetworkWatcherEventArgs>(HandleLostEvent);
            this.networkwatcher.Found -= new EventHandler<NetworkWatcherEventArgs>(HandleFoundEvent);
        }

        private void ListControllersView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem itemView = listControllersView.SelectedItems[0];

            if(itemView.Tag != null)
            {
                ControllerInfo controllerInf = (ControllerInfo)itemView.Tag;

                if(controllerInf.Availability == ABB.Robotics.Controllers.Availability.Available)
                {
                    if(this.controller != null)
                    {
                        this.controller.Logoff();
                        this.controller.Dispose();
                        this.controller = null;
                    }

                    this.controller = ControllerFactory.CreateFrom(controllerInf);
                    this.controller.Logon(UserInfo.DefaultUser);

                    RapidData rd = this.controller.Rapid.GetRapidData("T_ROB1", "RoboDK_Driver", "TESTVAR");

                    if (rd.Value is Num)
                    {
                        rapidNum = (Num)rd.Value;
                        VarValue = rapidNum.Value;
                    }

                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(controller.RobotWare.ToString() + " " + controller.State.ToString() + " " + controller.OperatingMode.ToString() + " " + "VarValue" + " " + VarValue);
                    this.listOutput.Items.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected controller not available");
                }
            }
        }

        void HandleFoundEvent(object sender, NetworkWatcherEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new
            EventHandler<NetworkWatcherEventArgs>(AddControllerToListView),
            new Object[] { this, e });
        }

        void HandleLostEvent(object sender, NetworkWatcherEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler<NetworkWatcherEventArgs>(RemoveControllerFromListView),
            new Object[] { sender, e });
        }

        private void AddControllerToListView(object sender, NetworkWatcherEventArgs e)
        {
            ControllerInfo controllerInfo = e.Controller;
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(controllerInfo.IPAddress.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.Id);
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.Availability.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.IsVirtual.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.SystemName);
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.Version.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(controllerInfo.ControllerName);
            item.Tag = controllerInfo;
            this.listControllersView.Items.Add(item);
        }

        private void RemoveControllerFromListView(object sender, NetworkWatcherEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(ListViewItem item in this.listControllersView.Items)
            {
                if((ControllerInfo)item.Tag == e.Controller)
                {
                    this.listControllersView.Items.Remove(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about the Winforms ListView, it does not do data binding and is not even a grid control.  Use a DataGridView, bind it to a datasource so that when you update that source, the DGV will update all by itself

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 Hi researched to DataGridView option on the weekend. But I still don't know how to implement the code for such an object. I just found tutorials on how to excess a sql database. Do you have a tutorial where I can look this things up?